# Curl not working Windows 10 cmd

Tags: curl, cmd, windows-10

I have installed Curl on Windows 10, 64 bit OS.

Curl version is 7.57 and its path is C:\Program Files\curl-7.57.0\AMD64

I have copied the ca-bundle file to this location where curl.exe is present.

Also added this path in the System environment variable PATH.

But when I open the cmd and type curl, it gives no response whatsoever and also no error is seen.

What should be done to make curl work here? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## cURL on Windows

*Skip to second section for more direct solutions*

I have had a lot of issues with cURL on Windows.  For example, and I realize your issue is likely much different than this, the following cURL command for RabbitMQ's HTTP API works great on Linux but does not work with the latest version of cURL on Windows 10.

```
curl -i -v -u root:root -H "content-type:application/json" -XPOST -d'{"vhost":"/","name":"amq.default","properties":{"delivery_mode":1,"headers":{}},"routing_key":"EMAIL","delivery_mode":"1","payload":"dasdfasdf","headers":{},"props":{},"payload_encoding":"string"}' http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/amq.default/publish
```

I realize this might be a roundabout answer but I would do the following:

1. In your start menu search for *settings* and click it
2. Select *Updates and Security*
3. Select *For Developers*
4. Enabled *Developer Mode*

Once that is enabled restart your computer.  Once the computer has started back up search for bash.exe. You now have access to an Ubuntu bash shell.  Run cURL from there.

You can read more about this from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/04/06/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-download-now-3/)

## More Direct solutions

If you don't want to do that I can think of two other things.

1. Place the binary (exe) file in your root c:\ drive and then update your path variable to reflect the new location.  Sometimes windows environment variables don't like spaces.  Similarly you can just put quotes around it `"C:\Program Files\curl-7.57.0\AMD64"`
2. If the above doesn't work, ,ake sure your path variable is set in system variables and not overridden in user variables by a path variable that doesn't include the location of your cURL binary file
3. If it still doesn't work then put the path of the curl binary as the first entry in your path variable.  I've also had windows path variable break when an entry before it was messed up... although I think that might have been fixed with windows 10.

Also, this is my personal preference, but I generally like to create create a new environment variable with the location. For example:

```
CURL     -     "C:\Program Files\curl-7.57.0\AMD64"
```

Then I append to the end of PATH a reference to the new CURL variable

```
%CURL%
```

I'm not saying this is necessary, just my preference.  The double quotes will probably fix your issue though.

Comment: Hi, I did as you said i.e. enabled developer mode etc. But no luck in cmd. However, works in powershell. Wtf?

Comment: I think you might have misread the directions.  It wont make it work in the windows command prompt, but you will have a bash.exe file you can open which is the Linux bash shell (Ubuntu) on Windows.  I think it works in powershell because it comes with powershell by default, its not using your exe.  In other words instead of open cmd.exe open bash.exe (similar to how you opened powershell.exe instead of cmd.exe).  I guess from an outside view it's no better than your current solution, although again I've found bash.exe's curl to be better for aforementioned reason

Comment: Try my first list item under "More direct solutions" as it might solve the issue outright.  But if you are ok with the workaround you figured out then nvm.  However I've had an issue with the powershell curl alias before as well.  IMHO using bash on windows has been way better than using a curl binary on windows or the one that comes with powershell. Also, in your path variable, put the path to your curl binary as the very first entry

Comment: The Ubuntu on Windows thingy worked though the path variable one didn't. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad the first one worked but a bit shocked the second section didn't.  I was pretty sure that would solve it outright.  Did you try with the double quotes (I ask because I made that edit after the initial post).  I honestly like using bash better and it's been way more reliable (especially concerning example cURL requests for different API's online).

Answer (score -1):

Add `-L` to follow redirections:

```
curl -fL <URL>
```